# Importing a date-time variable from Excel without losing 24 hour format

Tags: excel, date, time, import, stata

This is a snippet of my data in Excel:

```
trail_type  correct response    created_date
T_1_P_2     S       S           02-07-2018 17:42
T_1_P_1     L       L           02-07-2018 17:42
T_1_P_3     L       L           02-07-2018 17:42
T_1_P_4     L       S           02-07-2018 17:42
T_1_P_5     S       S           02-07-2018 17:42
```

As you will notice, the date-time is in a 24-hour format.

However, when I import the same data in Stata, I get the following:

```
trail_type  correct response    created_date
T_1_P_2     S       S           7/2/2018 5:42
T_1_P_1     L       L           7/2/2018 5:42
T_1_P_3     L       L           7/2/2018 5:42
T_1_P_4     L       S           7/2/2018 5:42
```

This happens even after importing everything as a string.

Below is the code I used to import:

```
import excel "abc.xls", sheet("xyz") firstrow allstring
```

Can someone guide me on how to get the proper import?

I need to either preserve the 24-hour format or get an AM/PM indicator.

The weird part is that if I simply copy paste the date-time from Excel onto the data editor in Stata, the 24-hour format is being preserved.

What kind of import command will work?

The problem is that I have hundreds of such files, so I need something in code, rather than me manually changing the column in each Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `format` of the imported date-time variable to the one desired.

The following should work:

```
. import excel "abc.xls", sheet("xyz") firstrow

. format created_date %tcDD-NN-CCYY_HH:MM

. list, noobs abbreviate(20)

  +------------------------------------------------------+
  | trail_type     correct   response       created_date |
  |------------------------------------------------------|
  |   T_1_P_2            S          S   02-07-2018 17:42 |
  +------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that the variable `created_date` will be numeric.

From Stata's command prompt, type `help format` for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this!